# How to automatically execute a Javascript function whenever width or height of a div changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to automatically execute a Javascript function whenever width or height of a div changes? I don't want to trigger an event manually. I am using jQuery.

Comment: When would the width or height of the div change?  As a result of what?  Window resizing?  Content changes?

Comment: Changes by jQuery's width() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this plugin:

- http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

From their example:

```
$("#unicorns").resize(function(e){
  // do something when #unicorns element resizes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no built in support for this.  the .resize() function is only for the window object, and the .change() function is only for input elements.  You will need to do it manually to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Doh, got owned by the guy below! :)